# addChildEventListener in service, need state of listeners

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a own service, that looks for data changes in the firebase database (via [child events](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/retrieve-data#child-events)).

This service is started on startup of the app:

```
Intent i= new Intent(this, DatabaseChangeHandler.class);
this.startService(i);
```

In the `DatabaseChangeHandler.class` are the `onChild...` listeners:

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent workIntent) {
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    DatabaseReference mDataset1 = mDatabase.child("dataset1");
    mDataset1.addChildEventListener(dataset1Listener);
    DatabaseReference mDataset2 = mDatabase.child("dataset2");
    mDataset2.addChildEventListener(dataset2Listener);
}
```

(They are not really named `dataset1` and `dataset2`)

But because I need the data in the activity after the startactivity, I need something like

```
if(dataIsRefreshed) {
    goToMainActivity();
} else {
    wait for dataIsRefreshed()
}
```

I know, that I should place the `goToMainActivity()` inside the `onChildAdded` or `onChildChanged` etc. but since I run this in a service, I'm not sure, how I can get the state of the listeners.